# Как правильно возвращать список параметров из функции и работать с ним

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть функция, которая возвращает список параметров. Эти параметры сохраняются в перменной lstVar. Обращение к значению переменных в lstVar происходит по порядковому номеру нужной переменной в списке. Все работает, но это не удобно, поскольку func1 постоянно находиться в процессе разработки и приходиться либо добавлять, удалять или менять порядок переменных в списке lstVar. Соотвественно нужно в коде не забыть поменять порядковые номера для получения значения нужных переменных. Вопрос - какой существуют более простой и красивый метод для решения озвученной проблемы. Я думаю использовать dictionary вместо list, чтобы получать данные по имени нужно переменной, а не по индексу. Возможно есть более красивое решение, которая не подразумевает привязку к порядку следования переменных в списке возвращаемых данных.

```
def func1():
    return [val1, val2, .... val30]

lstVar = func1()
var3 = lstVar[2]
```

Comment: У вас возвращается структура. Создайте класс и возвращайте его.

Comment: Проще всего наверное возвращать dict или named tuple

Comment: @MaxU, все таки лучше класс или namedtuple. По своему опыту могу сказать что с dict можно потом с полями запутаться, особенно если dict через несколько функций проходит - потом не понятно, почему в одном случае поле есть, в другом случае его нет, или почему иногда такой тип у поля, иногда другой, и т.д. Классы более дисциплинируют.

Comment: @insolor, согласен. С классами легче реализовать безопасный API со всевозможными проверками)

Comment: А можно маленький пример с классом? Не совсем понял идею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот самый простой пример

```
class Result:
    def __init__(self):
        self.param1 = 0
        self.param2 = 0

    def set_param1(self,value):
        self.param1=value

    def set_param2(self,value):
        self.param2=value

    def get_param1(self):
        return self.param1

    def get_param2(self):
        return self.param2


def f(x,y):
     res=Result()
     res.set_param1(y)
     res.set_param2(x)
     return res


params=f(2,4)
param1=params.get_param1()
param2=params.get_param2()
print(param1,param2)
```

Comment: Я сделал немного подругому. В самой функции объявил класс пустышку.  class output.   r = output().   r.var1 = val1, r.var2 = val2.  return r

Comment: Геттеры-сеттеры на каждое поле - не очень питоничный стиль (скорее джавовый), я бы таким не заморачивался. Тем более, что можно через `@property` сделать, для пользователя класса будет выглядеть как прямое обращение полям, а по сути будут те же геттеры-сеттеры внутри (если они так уж нужны).